# jQuery Draggable Not Working on Divi Website

Tags: jquery, draggable, divi

I haven't been coding much in the past couple of years and I don't remember how to fix this issue that I was able to fix before. I have a Divi website with some draggable class items and I can no longer drag them.

This is my code:

HEAD Code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

PAGE Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $("div.drag-me").draggable();
  } );
</script>
```

Each Element
Class: drag-me

Here is my page: https://akistepinska.com/divi/best-divi-font-combinations/

Thank you so much for your help.

I went to JQuery websites and tried to get the latest JQuery Head code links, but that didn't fix the issue. I double-checked my class assignments, and all the elements are assigned to the class.

Comment: Well if you look at the console on your website, it says it havent loaded jquery correct

Comment: It looks like you haven't included neither jquery or jquery-ui in your page. They are not present in your html when i inspect the page. Only jquery-ui.css is in your page

Comment: Thank you both for answering, I am not sure why the code is not on the page because in the Divi Theme Options I specified to add the JQuery scripts to the Head code.  I am going to add a screenshot of that. I tried to add a screenshot but I can't but under Divi Theme Options I enabled the Head Code to be added. I will try to reach out to Divi and see what is the reason it is not.

Comment: @AKAAKi157 Do you have any caching enabled? If so, clear the cache and reload the page to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Mat, I did purge cache multiple times (1. Purge SG Cache 2. Cleared & Preloaded cache, 3. Purge this URL 4. Clear the Used CSS of this URL with WP Rocket).

Comment: Update on this issue... I cleared the Static CSS File Generation under Divi Theme Options. Then, under Integration, removed the JQuery scripts and saved everything. Then I reloaded everything, and now the JQuery draggable option is working, but my Divi styles are not showing up in the Publish page, even though they are just fine in the preview. On Reddit, I saw a suggestion to roll-back to the previous Divi version and see if that will fix the issue. I will keep you guys updated.

Comment: SOLVED! Final update on this: I finally just decided to clone my page and redo it as a new POST, and it WORKED! I don't get it. The old page has everything the same, but the styling is not updating even though the JQuerry script is the same. The new page the style is updated, and draggable JQuery function works. https://akistepinska.com/divi/best-divi-fonts/